# Как подключиться к БД через HTML?

Tags: javascript, html5, cordova, build

Разрабатываю мобильное приложение на **html**.

Пробилдил его через **build.phonegap.com**. Дизайн страниц наполнил тестовыми данными которые закреплены в коде страницы, и редактируются только от туда.

Мне же необходимо динамически вытаскивать информацию с БД, и отображать ее на странице. Для этого нужно соответственно обратиться к серверу, и по запросу вытаскивать информацию.

**Как осуществить это обращение к серверу?** 
К сожалению **Cordova** обязательно требует чтобы главный файл был **.html**..

Если бы можно было использовать **php** то тогда проблем бы не возникло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). Делайте так: запрос из приложения к файлу php на сервере => файл отдает данные в JSON => делаете что надо.

Answer (score 2):

тут у вас вопрос общий.

есть 2 стороны.

1. Телефон (cordova приложение);
2. сервер (в интернете).

теперь определитесь.

1. на телефоне основной файл должен быть .html;
2. базу телефона можно использовать через js;
3. обращение к серверу тоже через js (html только стартер и интерфейс).

со стороны сервера

1. службы можно и в php сделать ;
2. базу тоже на усмотрение.

Обрашение из cordova к серверу

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=phonegap", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
```

Обрашение к базе телефона из cordova

```
 function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
    }
```

[ссылка](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase)

Comment: База и службы да, на php. Как мне можно обратиться к серверу через js? Как это будет выглядеть? На php там все можно вытащить через query. Там понятно. А как с JS....

Comment: вы будете из php обрашатся к базе, а из телефона к php. телефон будет работать через GET запросы. а php будет эти запросы обрабатывать

Answer (score 0):

Никто вам не мешает в ваше приложение добавить JavaScript
и при помощи ajax  загружать данные.

Можно использовать библиотеку [JQuery](https://jquery.com/).